# Highcharts change the line color if its out of the area range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

quickly run through the highcharts documentation, i wasn't able to find any options to change the color of the line that is out of the area range. 
could anyone advice a way to approach that problem. thanks in advance.

what i'm trying to achieve is something similar to

[image]

```
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line

http://jsfiddle.net/277x657h/2/
```

Comment: You can try to apply zones: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8nvk04t5/

Comment: @KamilKulig right right, thanks a lot, the only issue at the moment is to define these zones properly before passing them into a chart, i'll try to mull this over and post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Using Highcharts [Zones](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.zones) we can change the color at certain intervals.
I am expanding on [@KamilKulig's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654716/highcharts-change-the-line-color-if-its-out-of-the-area-range#comment86359948_49654716).

If you use linear lines for points and for the arearange, you can also calculate the intersection of the arearange and the line. It would look something like this: (Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keshprad_dev/agux3zte/82/) that demos this.)

```
function findAnomalyZones(intervals, values) {
  let validColor = '#25cc7b', anomalyColor = '#ff5f5f';
  let zones = Array();
  let prev = null;
  let anomalyType = null; // 1 for above Confidence interval. -1 for below
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        let interval = intervals[i], value = values[i];
    let zone = {value: value[0]};


        // point is an anomaly  
    if (value[1] < interval[1]) {
      anomalyType = -1;
      zone.color = anomalyColor;
    }
    else if (value[1] > interval[2]) {
            anomalyType = 1;
            zone.color = anomalyColor;
    }
    else {
        zone.color = validColor;
    }
    
    // Push prev zone if colors should be different
    // Update prev zone
        if (prev != null && prev.color != zone.color) {
        const interIdx = anomalyType == 1 ? 2 : 1;
      let {m: m1, b: b1} = findSlopeAndYIntercept([intervals[i-1][0], intervals[i-1][interIdx]], [interval[0], [interval[interIdx]]]);
      let {m: m2, b: b2} = findSlopeAndYIntercept(values[i-1], value);
      let {x, y} = findLineIntercept(m1, b1, m2, b2);
      
      prev.value = x
        zones.push(prev);
    }
    prev = zone;
  }
  
  zones.push({value: Date.UTC(9999), color: validColor})
  return zones
}

function findSlopeAndYIntercept(p1, p2) {
    const m = (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);
  const b = p1[1] - (m * p1[0])
  return {m, b}
}

function findLineIntercept(m1, b1, m2, b2) {
    let x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2);
  let y = (m1 * x) + b1
  return {x, y}
}

let zones = findAnomalyZones(intervals, values);
// PLOT THE HIGHCHART HERE
```

I am still not sure how you could calculate the intersection if using splines, but this works for linear graphs and arearanges.

Answer (score -2):

See the Highcharts documentation for Themes.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', 
         '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you be a little bit more specific on a way to use here, can't find out how it would help :)

Comment: if you go to the demo link you posted and click on any of the options where it says 'dark unica', 'sand signika', etc, there is a "view visual theme" button to see how they changed all the colors

Comment: the question is whether it's possible to change color not for the whole line, but for the piece that is out of the area range, if you make any dot extremely high/low the pick is supposed to be emphasised with different color, does any theme option really allow to achieve that?

Comment: @UladzislauKuzmin Themes is not what you want - see the comment on your post by Kamil regarding the use of `zones`